# browser performance after some ajax calls

Tags: ajax, jquery

I use `jquery` to make an ajax request every 15 seconds to update a `<DIV>` Element with information. That works generally fine but after some minutes, when the ajax request runs a few times, I got browser performance issues. I only need to run the page in firefox, but here is the problem most of all.

This is the way I call the function every 15 sec.:

```
setInterval(syncdiv, 15000);
```

This is my ajax request:

```
function syncdiv() {
    $.ajax({
          url: 'code_get_msg_sync.php?',
          cache: false, // The problem exist with cache true even with false
          success: function(data) {
            $('#msgdiv').html(data);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: How do those "performance issues" show? Does your console show anything, have you tried observing memory?

Comment: there is no console message. The page has drag and drop functionality. One performance issue is, that the drag events react very slow.

Comment: how are you tracking performance? could you show any samples or graph? Also, if you are using mvc or asp.net forms, you can use SignalR which is similar to websockets.

Comment: I don't use .net, sorry! I track the performance with Firebug. You can see that after a while the ajax call doesn't need 78ms instead it neets 1-2 sec.

Comment: Are the drag/drop events attached to the elements inside #msgdiv or to #msgdiv itself?

Comment: Where exactly is the time being spent - is it in the network request to retrieve the data or in setting the content of the element (render/reflow/paint)?

Comment: Yes, there are drag & drop events attached to the elements inside of #msgdiv. #msgdiv is dropable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
e.preventDefault();
```

before you submit or click to send a ajax request ..Just a try

Also there are few links for reference

**[Link 1](http://loadimpact.com/blog/ajax-get-or-post-which-is-best)**

**[Link 2](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#ajax_get)**

**[Link 3](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post/)**